# Loading weights into a keras model from a .pb filed generated by tf.simple_save() in TensorFlow 1.15.2

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am struggling with restoring a keras model from a `.pb` file. I have seen a couple of posts explaining how to do inference using a model saved in `.pb` format, but what I need is to load the weights into a `keras.Model` class.

I have a function that returns an instance of the said original model, but untrained. I want to restore the weights of that model from the `.pb` file. My goal is to then truncate the model and use the truncated model for other purposes.

So far the furthest I've gotten is using the `tf.saved_model.load(session, ['serving'], export_dir)` function to get a `tensorflow.core.protobuf.meta_graph_pb2.MetaGraphDef` object. From here I can access the graph_def attribute, and from there the nodes.

How can I go from that to getting the weights and then loading those into the instance of the untrained keras Model?

Maybe if that's not doable there is a way to "truncate" the graph_def somehow and then make inference using that?

Comment: To know about Tensorflow keras save and restore model and weights, go through this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load). Thanks!